# Retrieve subscribers status after deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, subscriber, status

I need to retrieve the historic of our subscribers status after a deletion process that deleted all of them.
After the deletion of the contacts, we re-imported the database however the status (unsub / Bounce / held) are missing.

I've testing the query to find subscribers status (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_query_find_subscriber_status_ref.htm&type=5) but it is not working (status is still blank).

Is there a way to retrieve the historic that have been lost.
(for info We are mainly working with query).

Thanks,
Mana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a subscriber is deleted all information regarding this subscriber is gone.

This is covered in the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5)

> If you delete a contact using Contact Delete in Contact Builder, we remove all contact information from all your sendable data extensions in your account. This removal includes any tracking or preference information. If this contact is added back into Contact Builder at a later time, the record receives a brand new unique ID and doesn’t retain any of the previous contact record's information.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.